# Using a variable in selector with the data-id attribute

Tags: javascript, css-selectors

I have some images that have  a data- attribute like:

```
    <img id="popup" class="Absolute_Center is_Image" alt="Girl Popup" data-picture="">

         <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/example.jpg" data-picture = "1">
         <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/example2.jpg" data-picture = "2">
         etc...
```

I want to add an event listener to retrieve the next picture in the series. I figured I can do this:

```
var oimgPopup = document.getElementById("popup");


/* retrieve data-picture value of current image showing in the image popup */
var y = oimgPopup.dataset.picture;
     var y = oimgPopup.dataset.picture;
     y = y + 1;
     // Prints out corect data-picture value + 1

     var nextImage = document.querySelector('[data-picture =' + y + ']');
     console.log(nextImage);
     /* SyntaxError: An invalid or illegal string was specified
        var nextImage = document.querySelector('[data-picture =' + y  + ']'); */
```

where I will retrieve the next image element object in the series and then I will insert it into #mypopup image element. However I am getting an illegal string message when I run this. Does anyone know how to incorporate a variable into the querySelector attribute selector? Thanks in advance...

Comment: You are forgetting to cl      ose your image tags

Answer (score 3):

When you use a [attribute selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-selectors) like `[attr = value]`,

> Attribute values must be CSS [identifiers](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier) or [strings](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#strings).

You didn't quote the value, so it's parsed as an [identifier](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier). However,

> In CSS, identifiers [...] cannot start with a digit

Therefore, your numerical selector is invalid. You can:

- Escape the value, e.g. if `y` is `123` you need `\31 23`

  ```
  document.querySelector('[data-picture =' + CSS.escape(y) + ']')
  ```
- Use strings, e.g. if you know `y` does not contain quotes,

  ```
  document.querySelector('[data-picture = "' + y + '"]')
  ```

Comment: When console.log after y = y+1 it is concatenated not added. Do i Have to do a Parseint() , add to y , then a back to string y.toString ()?

Comment: Much better answer than my own. I'd completely forgotten about the 'must not start with a digit' restriction.

Comment: @alan I don't like `parseInt`. I would use `y = +y + 1`. And it will already be coerced to a string when concatenated with strings, so `toString` is not needed.

Comment: That did it!. Thanks I was struggling with this. But you banged it out in a minute. I have to research that +y + 1 because I didn't know how you would increment a string.

Comment: just one thing. I was ok with using data-picture = "1" because I designating one as a string, correct?

Comment: @alan `+y` coerces `y` to a number. `data-picture = "1"` is a valid HTML attribute, and `data-picture = 1` too. But `[data-picture = 1]` is not a valid CSS attribute selector, you need `[data-picture = \31]` or `[data-picture = "1"]`